# JQuery UI Tabs - rebinding events for tabs loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Is there a proper way to rebind events in JQuery UI when tabs are loaded via ajax.  For example, in the code below, I have the success event call an 'initBinding()' function which sets up some custom click event handlers for different classes.  The problem with this is, when I switch tabs a bunch of times, then fire off one of the click events, I get some weird screen flicker effects.  If I refresh the entire page, then go directly to the click event, it doesn't flicker.  So I think it has something to do with it binding multiple times.

If I take the 'initBinding()' method out of the success event, any tab that gets loaded via ajax will not trigger any of the events I have setup.  Is there a standard/better way to do handling binding events like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var tabID = "#ui-tabs-" + (ui.index + 1);
            $(tabID).html("<b>Fetching Data....Please wait....</b>");
        },
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                $(anchor.hash).html("Could not load tab data");
            },
            success: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                initBinding();
            }
        }
    });
});
function initBinding() {
    $(".editButton").click(function () {
        //event logic...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use jQuery's [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

In your code:

```
$(".editButton").click(function () {
```

will become

```
$(".editButton").live('click', function () {
```

Using this technique, you can remove the `initBinding()` function altogether, and use the `.live()` statement in the onready function.

Comment: Is there a similar mechanism for binding classes to jquery ui methods?  For example, if I have $('div.accordion').accordion();.  If I load a page via ajax that has a div with an class of 'accordion', it is not loaded with the accordion effect.  Is there a something similar to live() that works in that scenario?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.